# Excel workbook locked for editing by me?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I'm having trouble with Excel fairly frequently saying that the workbook I'm trying to open is locked for editing by "another user" or "jmichael" (which is me).

Now in none of these instances did I have the file open (on any machine, nor in background). In some cases I won't have touched the file for weeks. What I suspect is that the ownership isn't being released properly when I close the file. I base that on the fact that A) if I open read-only, close the window, and then re-open, I get no such warning; B) it seems to happen more with files closed via macro.

I was hoping someone might be able to provide guidance on what might be causing this. I'm running Excel 2013 in Win7. If it matters, it's a virtual machine (I've run like this on a more limited basis at prior employers with no issue, but would believe I just hadn't done so enough to hit this case). As mentioned above, I have a way to clear the fake ownership, I'd just like to fix (or get IT to fix) whatever is causing the issue in the first place.

Thanks!

Comment: you left the excel file open and locked the computer. IT or a server script closed the connection you lost access to the file or an abrupt computer turn off and now your excel document left behind something akin to a lock file that is in the same directory as your excel file. it is hidden so you will have to change folder options to view hidden files and delete that lock file.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the Details Pane in Windows Explorer.

Open Windows Explorer

Click Organize (top left under the File menu)

Click Layout

Click Details Pane

The Details Pane gathers information about the file and while doing so, puts a "lock" on it.

Comment: I've implemented and so far haven't run into the issue, though I've only opened a couple files. I'll wait until I've gone a couple days before accepting just to be sure. In the mean time, I believe my personal computer has Details Pane turned on but doesn't experience this issue. Do you know why I might be getting the different behaviors? My guess would be something about how IT configured the computer, but I'm just curious what that might be.